# Unable to "show native code" in call stack?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, I don't see the option to show the full call stack including native code when right-clicking on methods in the call stack.

I've tried setting `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> "Enable Just My Code"` to unchecked. I was unable to investigate the registry hack mentioned, because the path does not exist on my system.

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/10/24/show-external-code/.

No code is suitable for demonstrating the issue, but please see the image.

[image: Cannot show native code.]

I see `[Native to Managed Transition]`, but expect more detail such the methods above and below that begin with `win32`. Furthermore, I expect to see `Show Native Code` when right-clicking on a method in the call stack, but do not.

Comment: The blog post is not relevant, it doesn't talk about native code or C++.  You already see the native code, like WinMainCRTStartup through invoke_main().  There are no extra methods before or after the transitions.  Having WinMain() compiled with /clr in effect is not a great idea, but the C++/CLI compiler can support it.  The only problem is that you don't have a problem.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, I turned off `/clr` and now see `kernel32.dll` and `ntdll.dll`, which is what I wanted. Turns out that having `/clr` was the "problem", if you can call it that!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Hans Passant, turning off `/clr` achieves the desired effect. I had no idea it was even on!